# node type not getting in search template

Tags: theming, search

I am referring to document [search-result.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--search--search-result.tpl.php) on Drupal.org. Here they say `$info_split['type']` has the node type information, but when I print in the file search-result.tpl.php in my theme folder, it does not print anything, as that key does not exist.  So is there something that I should do to get this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look into the code and it seems to be that is not implemented. So maybe it's a bug or just mistake in the documentation.

At least, you can reach your goal with the [`hook_node_search_result`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_search_result/7) or even with [`template_preprocess_search_result`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--search--search.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_search_result/7) if you don't want create a module.

For information, the `$info_split` for node is filled by [`node_search_execute`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_search_execute/7) that call the hook said above.

Answer (score 1):

$info_split['type'] has been used in Drupal 6. It's gone in Drupal 7 so the documentation is not right.

Below my code for extending the $info_split array with type. I also extended it with the node revision timestamp to use custom format_date() in my template.

`function template_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['result']['node']->type)) {
    $variables['info_split']['type'] = $variables['result']['node']->type;
  }
  if (isset($variables['result']['node']->revision_timestamp)) {
    $variables['info_split']['revision'] = $variables['result']['node']->revision_timestamp;
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I am using Apache Solr. `$variables['result']['node']->type` doesn't exist. `$variables['result']['node']->bundle_name` exists.

```
function my_theme_name_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['result']['node']->bundle_name)) {
    $variables['info_split']['type'] = $variables['result']['node']->bundle_name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8 :

```
function theme_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['result']['node']->getType()) {
      $variables['info_split']['node_type'] =$variables['result']['node']->getType();
  }
}
```